# Annulus properties

Tags: general-topology

Given the annulus

$$S = \left\lbrace x\in\mathbb{R}^{2}\mid 1\leq \|x\| < 2\right\rbrace$$

I claim that it is neither open nor closed. Is my reasoning below correct?

So, the annulus could be described as figure created by drawing $2$ circumferences: inner circumference and outer circumference. I will be using these circumferences to describe my reasoning.

"Closed" would mean that complement of $S$ is open, which is area inside the inner circumference together with area outside of out outer circumference. Since outer circumference is not in $S$, it belongs to complement of $S$. Hence, area outside of $S$ is not open. Hence, $S$ is not closed.

But at the same time, $S$ is not open. Because inner circumference is in $S$. Hence, $S$ is not open.

And of course, it is not compact (because it is not closed) and not convex (try to draw a line and you might cross area inside inner circle).

Comment: Why do you think it is not open?

Comment: Why does the cirferences belonging to a set mean the set isn't open?  Eventually you are going to have state what open or closed *means* and what the heck circumference have to do wot it.

Comment: @gary, because it contains inner circumference. Suppose, we take a point at this circumference. Then, if we draw a ball at this point, it will not be open (it will contain points in complement of S).

Comment: @fleablood, taking a point at a circumference leads us to taking a point at which we cannot draw a ball that would contain points of S. Hence, we cannot draw an open ball. Hence, the set is not open. Is this reasoning correct?

Comment: That is better, but still missing details.  You should be explicit about *which* points are in the complement of $S$ specifically.  If the ball is of radius $0<\epsilon<1$ then give a specific example of a point $x$ on the inner circumference and a point in the ball centered around $x$ of radius $\epsilon$ which is in the complement of our set.  Then try to be just as specific and rigorous with the open boundary on the outer circumference of the annulus.

Comment: @JMoravitz, thanks for the comment. I think the main part is to understand the idea, and putting it on paper is just working on details (I'm not saying details aren't important). The reason I did not provide details like explaining about balls and providing sigmas, is for this questions I just need to know if I got the right idea.

Comment: My apologies, I did not see the $\geq$ in the inner part.

Comment: Yes, the idea is important but to tell you if you have the idea we have to know why you *think* you have the idea which you have to communicate to us.  Then having the idea is the very easy part.  (The set isn't closed because the large circumference has edge points in it and it isn't open because the small circumference has points on the edge that straddle and are completely in).  But actually that is *not* the important part.  The important part is being able make meaningful and coherent statements to express it. And you are at the point where you must prove you *can* do details.

Comment: The picture gives you the idea, but a proof must be more rigorous. The ideas are OK, but you need details.

Comment: Can you try to show that $S$ is not closed by showing that it does not contain all of its limit points? Can you do the same for $S^C$?

Comment: You can say that $S$ is not closed because $2=\lim_{n\to \infty}(2-2^{-n}) \in  \overline S$ \ $S$, and the complement $S^c$ is not closed because $1=\lim_{n\to \infty}(1-2^{-n}) \in  \overline {S^c}$ \ $S^c.$

Comment: You can make the situation a bit easier: if $S$ is oper or closed, then so is its intersection with $[0, ∞) × \{0\} \cong [0, ∞)$, so it is enough to prove that $[1, 2)$ is neither open nor closed.